# Scanner terminating early

Tags: go

I am trying to write a scanner in Go that scans continuation lines and also clean the line up before returning it so that you can return logical lines. So, given the following SplitLine function ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/1HqqyvvcTJ)):

```
func ScanLogicalLines(data []byte, atEOF bool) (int, []byte, error) {
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    i := bytes.IndexByte(data, '\n')
    for i > 0 && data[i-1] == '\\' {
        fmt.Printf("i: %d, data[i] = %q\n", i, data[i])
        i = i + bytes.IndexByte(data[i+1:], '\n')
    }

    var match []byte = nil
    advance := 0
    switch {
    case i >= 0:
        advance, match = i + 1, data[0:i]
    case atEOF: 
        advance, match = len(data), data
    }
    token := bytes.Replace(match, []byte("\\\n"), []byte(""), -1)
    return advance, token, nil
}

func main() {
    simple := `
Just a test.

See what is returned. \
when you have empty lines.

Followed by a newline.
`

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(simple))
    scanner.Split(ScanLogicalLines)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf("line: %q\n", scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

I expected the code to return something like:

```
line: "Just a test."
line: ""
line: "See what is returned, when you have empty lines."
line: ""
line: "Followed by a newline."
```

However, it stops after returning the first line. The second call return `1, "", nil`.

Anybody have any ideas, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would regard this as a bug because an advance value > 0
is not intended to make a further read call, even when the returned token is nil ([bufio.SplitFunc](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc)):

> If the data does not yet hold a complete token, for instance if it has no newline while scanning lines, SplitFunc can return (0, nil) to signal the Scanner to read more data into the slice and try again with a longer slice starting at the same point in the input.

#### What happens is this

The input buffer of the `bufio.Scanner` defaults to 4096 byte. That means that it reads up to this
amount at once if it can and then executes the split function. In your case the scanner can read your input all at once as it is well below 4096 byte. **This means that the next read it will do results in `EOF`** which is the main problem here.

#### Step by step

1. [`scanner.Scan` reads all your data](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#127)
2. [You get all the text that is there](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#115)
3. You look for a token, you find the first newline which is only one newline
4. You return `nil` as a token by removing the newline from the match
5. [`scanner.Scan` assumes: user needs more data](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#127)
6. [`scanner.Scan` attempts to read more](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#165)
7. [`EOF` happens](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#168)
8. [`scanner.Scan` tries to tokenize one last time](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#115)
9. You find `"Just a test."`
10. [`scanner.Scan` tries to tokenize one last time](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#115)
11. You look for a token, you find the third line which is only one newline
12. You return `nil` as a token by removing the newline from the match
13. [`scanner.Scan` sees `nil` token and set error (`EOF`)](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bufio/scan.go?name=go1.1.2#130)
14. Execution ends

#### How to circumvent

Any token that is non-nil will prevent this. As long as you return non-nil tokens the 
scanner will not check for `EOF` and continues executing your tokenizer.

The reason why your code returns `nil` tokens is that `bytes.Replace` returns
`nil` when there's [nothing to be done](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/bytes/bytes.go?name=go1.1.2#641). `append([]byte(nil), nil...) == nil`.
You could prevent this by returning a slice with a capacity and no elements as
this would be non-nil: `make([]byte, 0, 1) != nil`.

Comment: Sorry, but is an empty string nil? Because when I add trace printouts, it prints out `advance=1, token="", err=<nil>`. Doing the same thing with the standard ScanLine print the same info, but scanning continues.

Comment: Testing a zero-length slice versus a nil value seem to show they are different. http://play.golang.org/p/lwWIomKcNF

Comment: No, the empty string is not nil. `nil` is the zero value for [some](http://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) types but not for string. `string([]byte(nil))` is however equal to the empty string. Are you (implicitly) converting `token` to a string? See [this version of your code with debug output](http://play.golang.org/p/HGEoxbqZ9j).

Comment: Ah, that explains it. The following code works as expected: http://play.golang.org/p/JoPy9sozb9. Note that the documentation do not state this, so that is at least a bug in the documentation. I find this behaviour very unintuitive and not very useful. It would be better to return the original slice in the event that there are no replacements, or a copy of it.