# Go: split byte.Buffer by newline

Tags: go

Pretty new to Go and running into a problem like:

```
var metrics bytes.Buffer

metrics.WriteString("foo")
metrics.WriteString("\n")

metrics.WriteString("bar")
metrics.WriteString("\n")
```

Now I want to cycle through that metrics and split by newline. I tried

```
for m := strings.Split(metrics.String(), "\n") {
     log.Printf("metric: %s", m)
}
```

but I get the following

```
./relay.go:71: m := strings.Split(metrics.String(), "\n") used as value
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering that [`strings.Split()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split) returns an array, it would be easier to use range

```
m := strings.Split(metrics.String(), "\n")
for _, m := range strings.Split(metrics.String(), "\n") {
    log.Printf("metric: %s", m)
}
```

Note, to read lines from a string, you can consider "[go readline -> string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6141604/6309)":

[`bufio.ReadLine()`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadLine) or better: [`bufio.Scanner`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner)

As in:

```
const input = "Now is the winter of our discontent,\nMade glorious summer by this sun of York.\n"
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
```

See more at "[Scanner terminating early](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19939219/6309)".

Comment: Definitely recommend using a string reader vs strings.Split. Splitting can leave you with unwanted characters such as \r on the end of your strings depending on your environment

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with a `bufio.Scanner`
Godoc at http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner

Something like this:

```
var metrics bytes.Buffer

metrics.WriteString("foo")
metrics.WriteString("\n")

metrics.WriteString("bar")
metrics.WriteString("\n")

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(&metrics)
for scanner.Scan() {
    log.Printf("metric: %s", scanner.Text())
}

if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

A full example here: http://play.golang.org/p/xrFEGF3h5P